# validate address to contain both numbers and names using regexp JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to validate the postal address to either contain street names and numbers or vice versa and not only names or numbers and i'm using regexp with my javascript function here. 
any assistance will be highly appreciated. thanks

```
function checkpostaladdress() {
        var postaladdressvalue = document.getElementById("postaladdress").value;
        if (postaladdressvalue.match(/\d\s?[A-Za-z] | [A-Za-z]\s?\d/)) {
            document.getElementById("postal_address_error").innerHTML = " postal address should contain at least street names and numbers";
            return false;
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("postal_address_error").innerHTML = "";
            return true;
        }
    }
<input type="text" id="postaladdress" name="postaladdress" placeholder="Postal Address" onkeyup="checkpostaladdress()"/><span id="postal_address_error"></span>
```

Comment: Are you sure thats not going to cause problems? There are plenty of addresses out there that dont have street numbers (e.g. rural plots or "named" addresses)?

Comment: It is restricted to a locality. Thats why its needed.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simple example that will just check that both numbers and alphanumeric characters are present. If you're looking to restrict possible formats, then googling will find *loads* of other regex questions on SO which may suit your requirements.

```
^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9])
```

As a simpler alternative, have you considered splitting the single field into **[Number]** and **[StreetName]** ? That would give you much more control and flexibility.